# Always exclude some rows from DbSet in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework 6 with database first. In a current project I have some rows in the database that never should be fetched by Entity Framework. Let's say that I have this simplified model:

```
    public partial class Customer
    {
        public Customer()
        {

        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Deleted { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class MyEntities: DbContext
    {
        public MyEntities()
            : base("name=MyEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    }
```

Every time I make an operation on the `Customer` `DBSet` I really just want to fetch items that have `Deleted == null`. This is because the system sometimes will mark Customers as deleted, and then the application should not be aware of these items (as if they didn't exist).

The model is way more complex in reality, which is why I want to control this at the `DbContext`-level, rather than adding a `Where()`-clause in every query.

***Is there any way to always exclude items based upon a column in the table?***

Something like so:

```
public partial class MyEntities: DbContext
{
    public MyEntities()
        : base("name=MyEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        Customers = Customers.Where(x => x.Deleted == null); // Obviously not working...
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit**:
This will be applied to approx 20-30 different entities in a complex model. So I would like to avoid views and manage it in code instead.

**Edit 2:**
Thanks for the tip about EntityFramework.DynamicFilters. However, it doesn't seem to support database first.

> Sorry, but when using Database First, we don't have any access to the
>   model configuration so this is not supported.

https://github.com/jcachat/EntityFramework.DynamicFilters/issues/41

Comment: In EF6, at least, you could achieve this with interceptors.  It might be easier to use a package that implements filters, though, like NHibernate.

Comment: Or [EntityFramework.DynamicFilters](https://github.com/jcachat/EntityFramework.DynamicFilters). See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34343982/861716

Comment: I'd call the linked answer from @GertArnold an effective duplicate of this question despite the fact that the questions are not related. But that answer is perfect.

Comment: Great. I'll check it out. Thank you.

Comment: EntityFramework.DynamicFilter seems to be a great package, but it currently does not support database first.

Answer (score 1):

How about making a custom view

> dbo.AvailableCustomers

like this:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.AvailableCustomers
AS SELECT * FROM Customers
Where Deleted IS NULL;
```

and then the Context's Customers DBSet will point to the new view.

Comment: Great idea. But in the end it will be implemented on a lot of tables. I've updated my question.